# Encripted private key error in paramiko happens only in some systems

Tags: python, paramiko

I am using paramiko to connect to several systems via SSH. I am able to connect successfully using a private key, but in one specific system, this exception is raised:

```
paramiko.PasswordRequiredException: Private key file is encrypted
```

If the private SSH key is indeed encrypted, why it'd would work with the other systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the real problem was that I was trying to login with a user which did not exist in the target system. Too bad that the non-intuitive error message did not help me to conclude that earlier.